# How to add .min and .debug files in a bundle effectively

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-optimization

I want to take advantage of `.min` and `.debug` versions of `js` and `css` files.

Consider this bundle for example:

```
 bundles.Add(
          new ScriptBundle("~/scripts/vendor")
            .Include("~/scripts/jquery-{version}.js")
            .Include("~/scripts/knockout-{version}.debug.js")
            .Include("~/scripts/knockout-{version}.min.js")
            .Include("~/scripts/knockout-{version}.js")
```

What is the correct mechanism to take advantage of each file. I mean how set some setting to make ASP.NET smart enough to use `.min` on final releases and `.debug` while debugging?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `.Include("~/scripts/knockout-{version}.js")` and ASP.NET will use `~/scripts/knockout-{version}.min.js` in production and `~/scripts/knockout-{version}.js` when debugging

Comment: What about .debug for some libraries?

Answer (score 2):

You can have the bundler switch between debug and non-debug files if you group them with a wildcard.  For example:

```
bundles.Add(
      new ScriptBundle("~/scripts/vendor")
        .Include("~/scripts/jquery-{version}.js")
        .Include("~/scripts/knockout-*")
```

Then include in knockout-version.debug.js and knockout-version.js in your ~/scripts/ path.

The bundler will use the debug version if you're in debug mode, or minify the non-debug version and use it if optimizations are enabled.